# What is the moment generating function of Dirichlet distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

I want to find the moment generating function (or the Laplace transform) of the Dirichlet distribution. I know the moments can be found using the gamma functions as follows 
:$$E\left[\prod_{i=1}^K x_i^{\beta_i}\right]=\frac{B\left(\boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)}{B\left(\boldsymbol{\alpha}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}+\beta_{i}\right)}\times\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha_{i}+\beta_{i}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha_{i}\right)},$$ but what I am really interested in is the functional form of the MGF (or the Laplace transform) so that it can be used to find other sampling distributions thereof or any other transformation of the Dirichlet also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the MGF of the Dirichlet by consulting pages 15 and 16, here:

https://mast.queensu.ca/~communications/Papers/msc-jiayu-lin.pdf

This work is not mine.  It is simply a reference I found online.

Original, now dead: http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~web/Papers/msc-jiayu-lin.pdf

Comment: the link is dead by now

Comment: @deemel, I found a new link to the document online.  I hope but can't guarantee this is permanent.

Comment: Looks like it has moved again, to here: https://mast.queensu.ca/~communications/Papers/msc-jiayu-lin.pdf. For future reference, it's "On The Dirichlet Distribution," a 2016 Master of Science report by Jiayu Lin.

Answer (score 0):

You may compute it along the following lines: let $E_n$ be the set: 
$$E_n = \left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n): x_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=1\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n.$$
Then:
$$ \int_{E_n} x_1^{\alpha_1-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot x_{n}^{\alpha_n-1}\,d\mu = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}\Gamma(\alpha_i)}{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\ldots+\alpha_n)}$$
for any choice of the $\alpha_i$ such that $\text{Re}(\alpha_i)>0$.

Comment: I can compute the moments, but what I really need is the moment generating function M(t1,t2,t3,...,tn).

Comment: If you are able to compute moments you are able to compute the moment generating function too, @Udita.

Comment: Hi Jack, yes, that is true. The moments can be used to know the value of differential of MGF at 0. But I want to know if there is a nice mathematical form of M(t1,t2,..,tn) for arbitrary t's.

Comment: @Udita: again, if you know the Taylor coefficients in zero of an entire function, you know the values of such a function everywhere.

Comment: That's true. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sure, it is possible to know the values, but is it possible to express the MGF in some nice mathematical form (like the MGF of the gamma distribution, for example), rather than expressing it as an infinite sum?